# Count of newline in databases

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql, newline

How databases count newlines (carriage return CR, line feed LF). For example with a column type **varchar(10)**:

```
abcdef
gh
```

Will be count as **9** or **10**?

**Edit:**
I tested with PostgresSQL and it gives 9, is it the same for the others?

Comment: How about you test it for yourself? It takes about one minute max, including table creation and testing.

Comment: I should have explained it better. I wanted to know how most important databases count new lines, since I have PostgreSQL installed and can't test in others. But with the answer of [Joe Taras](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2577734/joe-taras), I see its possible with [Sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is 9:

I've tried your query on Sql Fiddle with MySql 5.5.32 version, Postgres 9.3.1, Sql Server 2012.

[MySql Sql Fiddle trial](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee48b/1/0)

[Postgres 9.3 Sql Fiddle Trial](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ee48b/1/0)

[Sql Server 2012 Sql Fiddle Trial](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ee48b/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT LENGTH(your_column_name_here) FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below snippet

```
mysql> select length('abcdef
    '> gh');
+---------------------+
| length('abcdef
gh') |
+---------------------+
|                   9 |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```